How to make table as full page width in PDF generation in Flutter?
I'm generating PDF in my flutter app using pdf package pdf pub dev link, I have a table in it and would like to stretch the table to full page size
instead of having the following:

To make the table start from the most left of the page, till the most right of the page without the (e.g. use 1 & 2 sections in the picture instead of leaving empty)
My table code is as following:
pw.TableHelper.fromTextArray(
      border: null,
      headerDecoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: const pw.BorderRadius.all(pw.Radius.circular(2)),
        color: PdfColor.fromHex('#108dcd'),
      ),
      headerCellDecoration: cellDecoration,
      cellPadding: const pw.EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
      headerHeight: 25,
      cellHeight: 25,
      columnWidths: getTableColumnsWidth(tableHeaders),
      cellAlignments: getTableColumnAlignment(tableHeaders),
      cellDecoration: getTableCellDecoration,
      headers: List<pw.Text>.generate(
        tableHeaders.length,
        (col) => tableHeaders[col],
      ),
      data: getDataTable(tableHeaders, quotationRoomsList),
    ),

while the width of the columns is:
Map<int, pw.FlexColumnWidth> getTableColumnsWidth(tableHeaders) {
  return {
    0: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(0.05),
    1: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(0.20),
    2: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(0.31),
    3: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(0.14),
    4: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(0.13),
    5: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(0.17),
  };
}


Which package are you using for creating tables and pdf generation? Kindly mention in detail about the same

@Prashant you are right, forgot to mention, I'll edit my question
https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

I assume the space you get on the left and right is not related to the table (which itself spreads across the entire width) but rather caused by the page margin. The MultiPage class e.g. has a margin property which is probably what you are looking for.

@jarinox but this attribute will be applied to everything in the page, I just want the table to be stretched

but your answer got me to think about setting the table in container and set horizontal margin as negative and it worked :)

I have wrapped the pw.TableHelper.fromTextArray with a Container and set the margin attribute of the container to negative number.
pw.Container(
      margin: pw.EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: -45),
      child: pw.TableHelper.fromTextArray(
        border: null,
        ...),
 ),

what jarinox suggester in the comment will work if need to set margin for all the page, hence, all widgets in it will be impacted.
in my case I wanted only the table to be stretched.
